# Install Python Wheel when starting Docker Containers with docker-compose

Tags: docker, apache-spark, docker-compose, jupyter-notebook

We are currently developing a python package, which will be build via an AzureDevOps Pipeline and the result package will be stored in the Azure Artifacts.

In production we install that package directly to some databricks clusters directly from the Azure Artifacts. Benfit is, whenever a new Version of the package is available, it is getting installed when starting a cluster

For developing, i want to do the similar within a local spark environment with docker container. We already set up docker containers which are working fine except one thing.

When i run my docker-compose command, i want to install my package from AzureArtifacts with the latest version.
Because we need access tokens to get this package in our setup, i can't provide this tokens in a git Repo. Therefore i need a way to provide the token safely to a docker-compose command and install the package from startup.

Also, if using the Dockerfile for the command, each time we will get a new version of our package, i have to build the docker-images again.

So this tasks need to be done from the user in my mind (assume DockerImages are already build):

1. Have a local file where a token is stored
2. Use my Docker-compose command to start up a local environment (by the way, with spark-master and workers and jupyter-notebook)
3. Automatic: get the token from the local file, provide it to any startup-script in the docker container and install the package from Azure Artifacts.

As i am no real expert on Docker, i found some topics regarding to ENTRYPOINT and CMD, but didn't understand that and what exactly to do.

Have anyone a hint which way we can go to easily implement that above logic?

PS: For testing i tried to install the package with command: during docker-compose with plaintext token, the installation worked but the juypter notebook was not accessible anymore :-(

Hopefully anybody has an idea or a better approach for what i am aiming to do.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use [build-args](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg):

```
docker-compose build --build-arg ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME=<your_username> --build-arg ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD=<your_password> <service_to_build>
```

then your Dockerfile might look like:

```
FROM <my_base_image>

ARG ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME
ARG ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD

RUN pip install <your_package_name> --extra-index-url https://$ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME:$ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD@pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org>/_packaging/<your_package_name>/pypi/simple/
...
```